# Как сжать apk в ProGuard?

Tags: android

Есть 5 библиотек. Все они подключаются через Gradle
В каждой либе есть support.v7 и support.design.

Можно ли как то отключить их, и оставить только одну. А то из за них размер апк весит не 3 мегабайта, а целых 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В APK библиотеки не дублируются **поумолчанию**. Даже более того, gradle не сможет собрать APK, если в нем будут дублирующиеся классы. Так что проблема у вас точно не в дублирующихся библиотеках. Откройте APK, как обычный архив, достаньте оттуда `classes.dex`, декомпилируйте, посмотрите, что занимает много места. А еще приведите свой конфиг proguard'a в вопрос.

Comment: Что вы говорите. Вообще - то в ProGuard есть функция пропуска дублирующих классов. А если он пропускает то значит он их игнорит во время проверки. А при компиляции используются 2 класса одинаковых. Из - за которых и увеличивается размер файла

Comment: @xTIGRx, что за функция?

Comment: exclude, можно указывать в разделе dependes. Где добавляются ссылки на либы типо. compile ' '. Было бы правильнее не использовать их. Но я протестил и она их просто пропускает во время проверки.

Comment: @xTIGRx Вот официальный референс всех методов ProGuard, и `exclude` там нет http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/refcard.html

Comment: Я использую ProGuard 5.2 так как 4.7 не пашет с java 8.

А как тогда exclude  у меня работает?)

Comment: @xTIGRx, покажите, как вы его используете

Comment: Вот так
` compile (project(":plugin-imagecode-android:app")) {
        exclude (group: 'com.example.',module: 'coffe')
    }`

Comment: @xTIGRx, это в gradle файле? А где тут exclude?

Comment: Да в Gradle. Я обновил коммент выше

Comment: @xTIGRx, Так это не proguard. В общем, мой ответ остается в силе. Если не верите - декомпилируйте свое приложение, и убедитесь, что там только один набор классов.